# How to pass a racket object's field id as a function argument

Tags: object, lisp, racket

I have the example object

```
(define test-class%
  (class object%
         (super-new)
         (field [test-field 3])
         (field [test-field2 2])))
(define test-object (make-object test-class%))
```

Later on I have the code:

```
(set-data-field! env data-key test-field (+ val 1))
```

Which results in the error:
3.rkt:1548:42: test-field: unbound identifier in module
  in: test-field

I want to pass the field id to set-data-field! because the hashed object can be accessed by any thread and is protected via this code:

```
(define (set-data-field! env key field val)
 (let ([data (get-data env key)])
   (if data
     (let ()
       (semaphore-wait (get-data-sem env))
       (set-field! field (get-data env key) val)
       (semaphore-post (get-data-sem env))
       #t)
     #f)))
```

How can I pass a field id around to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t dynamically access a field using `get-field` or `set-field!` because they are macros, and the field name is provided statically (as a literal identifier, not as an expression that is evaluated). Fortunately, `racket/class` also provides [`dynamic-get-field`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._dynamic-get-field%29%29) and [`dynamic-set-field!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._dynamic-set-field%21%29%29), which are ordinary functions that accept symbols in place of field names. Using these functions, you can adjust `set-data-field!` to accept a field name:

```
(define (set-data-field! env key field val)
 (let ([data (get-data env key)])
   (if data
     (let ()
       (semaphore-wait (get-data-sem env))
       (dynamic-set-field! field (get-data env key) val)
       (semaphore-post (get-data-sem env))
       #t)
     #f)))
```

Then you can adjust your call to `set-data-field!` to pass the field name as a symbol:

```
(set-data-field! env data-key 'test-field (+ val 1))
```